# How to call and execute an operator from string?

Tags: javascript, operators

for example:

```
var s = '3+3';
s.replace(/([\d.]+)([\+\-)([^,]*)/g,
        function(all, n1, operator, n2) {
                r = new Number(n1) ??? new Number(n2);
                return r;
        }
);
```

note: not using `eval()`

Comment: Looks like one of the few cases where `eval()` would be handy.

Comment: Is `new Function()` off limits too?

Comment: Why not using `eval()` out of curiosity?

Comment: You might find the following series interesting: [Essentials of Interpretation](https://github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/Essentials-of-interpretation/). They are small lesson about computer program interpretation, written in Javascript, the goal at the end IMO will be to implement a small scheme-like language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Are Variable Operators Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/javascript-are-variable-operators-possible)

Not possible out of the box, but he gives a nice implementation to do it, as follows. Code by [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan).

```
var operators = {
    '+': function(a, b) { return a + b },
    '<': function(a, b) { return a < b },
     // ...
};

var op = '+';
alert(operators[op](10, 20));
```

So for your implementation

```
r = operators[operator](new Number(n1), new Number(n2));
```

Comment: +1 for using the object to look up operator functions instead of if/else or switch/case.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is a bit broken.

```
/([\d.]+)([\+\-)([^,]*)/g
```

should probably be

```
/([\d.]+)([+-])([\d+]+)/g
```

then you can switch on the operator:

```
function (_, a, op, b) {
  switch (op) {
    case '+': return a - -b;
    case '-': return a - b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
s.replace(/(\d+)\s*([+-])\s*(\d+)/g, function(all, s1, op, s2) {
  var n1 = Number(s1), n2 = Number(s2);
  return (op=='+') ? (n1+n2) : (n1-n2);
});
```