# Angular js eval inside bind

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm learing Angular JS and I'm currently in the process of understanding what it does and what it does not.

I'm trying to do a simple calculator that has two numbers and an operator as input.

I'm having a hard time to understand how to evaluate the operator on the binding. This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id='example' ng-app=''>
  <input ng-model='number1' type='number'>
  <select ng-model='operation' ng-options="op for op in ['+', '-', '/', '*']"></select>
  <input ng-model='number2' type='number'>
  <div id='output' ng-bind="number1 + number2"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of `number1 + number2` I want it to be something like `eval(number1 operator number2)` but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the if statement

```
<input ng-model='number1' type='number'>
<select ng-model='operation' ng-options="op for op in ['+', '-', '/', '*']"></select>
<input ng-model='number2' type='number'>
<div ng-if="operation == '+'"><div id='output' ng-bind="number1 + number2"></div></div>
<div ng-if="operation == '-'"><div id='output' ng-bind="number1 - number2"></div></div>
<div ng-if="operation == '/'"><div id='output' ng-bind="number1 / number2"></div></div>
<div ng-if="operation == '*'"><div id='output' ng-bind="number1 * number2"></div></div>
```

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/7hu2m0pw/)

Comment: But the id should be unique alongside the page. what `$("#output")` would return?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

In controller:

```
$scope.operators = {
    '+': function(a, b) { return a + b },
    '-': function(a, b) { return a - b },
    //...rest of the operators
};
```

in view:

```
<div id='output' ng-bind="operators[operation](number1, number2)"></div>
```

This is will keep your view cleaner without any redundant divs.

Inspired by this SO answer: [How to call and execute an operator from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356123/how-to-call-and-execute-an-operator-from-string)

Comment: seems like the best idea so far but my intention was to use only HTML and the `ng` properties.