# Convert equation string to equation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running an equation with Javascript from a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857726/running-an-equation-with-javascript-from-a-text-field)

How can I convert the following:

```
var n = "2x^3+3x+6";
```

To

```
var x = a number
var n = 2x^3+3x+6;
```

In JavaScript?

Comment: You'll have to write a parser for the expression grammar you intend to use.

Comment: The `^` operator in JavaScript is binary XOR, not the power as you seem to expect.

Comment: What operators are you expecting in the equation?

Comment: http://zaach.github.com/jison/

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all; the syntax in this question is definitely not JavaScript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quite hard to guess what the exact requirements and the context are, but if you want to roughly stick to the grammar demonstrated by your variable I'd suggest using a math expression parser.

Using [js-Expression-eval](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval), it could look like this:

```
var formula = "2*x^3+3*x+6";
var expression = Parser.parse(formula);
var result = expression.evaluate({ x: 3 });
```

Run the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBp2D/)

Should you want to have your own grammar - to leave out the * symbols for multiplication with variables, for example - you'll have to roll your own parser, for example using something like [jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/).

Comment: great super easy solution, thank you!

Answer (score 17):

```
var x = a number;
var n = eval("2*Math.pow(x,3)+3*x+6")
```

Comment: Where did you get `Math.pow` from `"2x^3+3x+6"`?

Comment: @PeteH the question isn't necessarily poorly-asked; perhaps the OP does not want to use JavaScript syntax for his equations.