# if/else defines plus or minus in function

Tags: javascript, math

I have two practically identical functions. The only difference between them are one has `+` and one has `-`. These are used about 20 times in each function, so I'd love to make this simpler with a var.

I'm still very new to JavaScript, so I don't know where to start, but something like:

```
if ( blah blah ){
    var symbol = '-';
} else{
    var symbol = '+';
}

var example = value1 [symbol] value2;
```

Thanks

Comment: This is nothing to do with jQuery really, it's JavaScript. I've added the tag for you.

Comment: You can try these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use this:

```
var modifier = (blah blah) ? 1 : -1;
var example = value1 + (modifier * value2);
```

Comment: how use it for * and /?

Comment: @KamilDąbrowski this only works for +/-. Check the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707843/2193252) for solutions that also work with different operators.

Comment: @KamilDąbrowski you can do a similar thing with * and /
`4 * 4 / (isDivision ?  (4 * 4) : 1)`

Answer (score 6):

You could define an object containing functions, keyed by the operator. Something like this:

```
var operations = {
    '+': function(a, b) { return a + b; },
    '-': function(a, b) { return a - b; }
}

var x = operations[condition ? '+' : '-'](value1, value2);
```

I think @darthmaim has the nicest method though, but it depends if you need to use other operators, such as `*`, `/` or `%`.

Comment: +1 - I was almost about to post the **same exact** thing. [Not kidding!] :-)

Answer (score 1):

why not so:

```
if ( blah blah ){
    var example = value1 - value2;
} else{
    var example = value1 + value2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `eval`, but I would use a function like this:

```
var op;
if (condition) {
    op = function(a, b) { return a - b; };
} else {
    op = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
}

var example = op(value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var math = {
    '+' : function(x,y) {return x + y;},
    '-' : function(x,y) {return x - y;}
}

var usePlus = true;
math[usePlus ? '+' : '-'](1,2) // returns 3
```