# Making single function to handle ==, !== in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I want to make a single function that can handle ===, !== to sort elements. I have no idea how to do this.Please suggest how can i do this

HTML

```
 <div class="aa">1</div>
  <div class="aa">2</div>
  <div class="aa">3</div>
  <div class="aa">4</div>
  <div class="aa">2</div>
  <div class="aa">6</div>
```

$val=2;

```
function getVal(div,symbol){
  div.filter(function () {
              return parseInt($(this).html(), 10)===$val;  //i want to use passed symbol in place of ===     
            }).show();
}

getVal($('.aa'),'===')
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/EzEREFU/2/

Comment: Might be of use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to apply some cleverness ;)

```
function getVal(div,invert) {
    div.filter(function() {
        return (parseInt($(this).html(),10) === $val) ^ invert;
    }).show();
}
```

That `^` is an XOR operator. It's supposed to be bitwise, but it works on booleans just fine.

To use:

```
getVal($(".aa"),false); // "==="
getVal($(".aa"),true); // "!=="
```

If you want to be able to pass in "===" or "!==", try this:

```
function getVal(div,symbol) {
    var invert = symbol.charAt(0) != "=";
    div.filter(function() {
        return (parseInt($(this).html(),10) === $val) ^ invert;
    }).show();
}
```

---

Obligatory [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) solution:

```
function getVal(className,symbol) {
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(className),function(elm) {
        if( (parseInt(elm.firstChild.nodeValue,10) === $val) ^ invert)
            elm.style.display = "block";
    });
}
getVal("aa","==="); // show where equal
getVal("aa","!=="); // show where not equal
```

What's that? Older browsers? Psh, sod 'em. If people deliberately make our lives difficult by disabling Windows Update, they don't deserve our awesome websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can not actually pass a string as an operator in javascript, unless you use `eval(..)` (which is typically not recommended). I'd suggest another option:

```
var equals = function(x,y) { return x === y; }
var notEquals = function(x,y) { return x !== y; }
```

Now,

```
function getVal(div,operation){
  div.filter(function () {
              return operation(parseInt($(this).html(), 10),$val);
            }).show();
}

getVal($('.aa'),equals); //equals defined above.
```

You can create custom functions like `equals`, `notEquals`, etc. Further, you can put them in a dictionary, and where keys are your "symbols", and the value is the function, and hence invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this -

```
$val=2;


function getVal(div,symbol){
  div.filter(function () {
    if(symbol=='equalsTo')
      return parseInt($(this).html(), 10)===$val;
    else if(symbol=='notEqualsTo')
      return parseInt($(this).html(), 10)!==$val;
  }).show();
}

getVal($('.aa'), 'notEqualsTo'); //notEqualsTo or equalsTo
```

example - http://jsbin.com/EzEREFU/4/