# A quick JavaScript variable tip?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just had a quick question about assigning a mathematical operator to a JavaScript variable.

So I have a variable called mathFunction like below...

```
var Mathfunction;
```

If I want to apply an actual mathematical operator would I just do something like this?

```
var Mathfunction = +;  Or var Mathfunction = '+';
```

Any advice for this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `var Mathfunction = '+'`  and use switch-case for each operator.

Comment: Chek this post, It may be solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834436/2436213

Comment: @Senthilmurugan interesting link thanks, he is using JS object! correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, at least not meaningfully. The firs option you posted throws a SyntaxError.

You could do `var Mathfunction = '+';` and `eval()` it, but **don't do that** - `eval()` is very unsafe. The real question is: why do this? If you are building a parser or logic engine, there are better ways to go about this.

Comment: I am trying to create a math game.

Comment: *"`eval()` is very unsafe."* No it's not. It's *how it is used* that *can* make it unsafe. If you have full control over the input, it is not unsafe.

Comment: @FelixKling I agree that it is how it's used that can make it unsafe, but it's complicated. You need full control *and* no errors in your logic or validation of input. `eval('2+2')` is perfectly safe. `eval(foo+Mathfunction+bar)` may be safe or may not be, but doing it in a way that you can be sure that it is safe is extremely difficult and prone to errors. Avoiding `eval()` in pretty much every language whenever possible is a best practice, for good reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the operator `var Mathfunction = '+';` for math matical operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Glad that you were willing to help.