# Undefined variable and concatenation. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to build a calculator using JavaScript without eval. I'm trying to concatenate a variable to store the numbers. Is this the correct way of doing so? Also, when ever I add to the variable it is preceded with undefined.

```
var calculator = {
    run: function(clicked){
        num1: "";
        num2: "";
        numCheck: false;

        switch(clicked){
            case "1":
                document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML += clicked;
                if(this.numCheck===false){
                    if(this.num1==="undefined"){
                        this.num1 = " ";
                        this.num1 = this.num1+"1";
                    }else{
                        this.num1 = this.num1+"1";
                    }
                }else{
                    calculator.run.num2 += "1";
                };
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: [Are Variable Operators Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible)

Comment: How does that relate to what I am asking?

Comment: "build a calculator using JavaScript **without eval**". You can use object's keys as Math operators. If you think it's not related to your question/problem, ignore it ;)

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude then, I think my question wasn't clear. I am wondering why when I perform +=1 on a variable the result is "undefined1" instead of 1.

Comment: This looks like string operations and not arithmetical

Comment: Then what kind of calculator is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

Missing `this` on declaration and wrong format on declaration you are using `:` instead of `=` inside `run` class/function the correct should be:

```
var calculator = {
    run: function(clicked){
        this.num1= "";
        this.num2= "";
        this.numCheck= false;
```

case missing `break` and `{` like:

```
 switch(clicked){
            case "1":{
              //... your code.
              break; 
             }
```

Inside your function while using properties that belongs to the class those should be accessed using `this` instead of using the var `calculator` on:

```
calculator.run.num2 += "1";
```

Correct should be

```
this.run.num2 += "1";
```

And this can be converted into a single like:

```
this.num1 = " ";
this.num1 = this.num1+"1";
```

Like:

```
this.num1 = " 1";
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that when doing so the variable then becomes "undefined1" instead of "1". Thank you for the help with the rest of the code. Why would I need to define it as a var or this within an object? Isn't that a given?

Comment: 'when doing so...'. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, when performing +=1 to the variable it becomes "undefined1" instead of 1.

Comment: @hudsond7 `num1: "";` is not a valid way to declare the variable therefore `this.num1 += "1"` is actually undefined. This is included in my post above.