# How to take plus sign in variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to calculate two numbers and its pretty simple.

But Is there any way to take operator in variable and then do the calculation?

```js
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
var p = '+';
var z = x + p + y;

$(".button").click(function() {
  alert(z);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click ME !</div>
```

Comment: A simple `switch...case` would do.

Comment: Here's answer to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible

Comment: If you only need to decide between `+` and `-` you can also just multiply with `var p = 1` or `var p = -1`.

Answer (score 15):

Avoid `eval` whenever possible. For this example, a simple `switch...case` statement will be sufficient:

```
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
var z;
var p = "+";
switch (p) {
    case "+":
        z = x + y;
        break;
    case "-":
        z = x - y;
        break;
}
```

---

You can also use a map of functions:

```
var fnlist = {
    "+": function(a, b) { return a + b; },
    "-": function(a, b) { return a - b; }
}
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
var p = "+";
var z = fnlist[p](x, y);
```

Comment: I'm really liking the func map solution... Very elegant!

Answer (score 7):

Or use parseInt on the string which you will be adding the variable to:

```js
 var x = 5;
 var y = 5;
 var p = '-';
 var z = x + parseInt(p + y);

$(".button").click(function(){
  alert(z);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click ME !</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution not using `eval`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function:

```js
 var x = 5;
 var y = 5;
 var p = '+';
 var z = x + p + y;

$(".button").click(function(){
  alert(eval(z));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click ME !</div>
```

However, you have to remember that using `eval` function is potentially risky. For example, if used in the wrong way it can allow one to make injection attacks. Debugging can be also more difficult. **I suggest to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).**

Comment: Thanks ! Done ..Will accept it after 10 min ..Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Twix - remember that using `eval` comes with some warnings - the function will attempt execute **any** JS code that it is provided. Take care to ensure you are only executing code you intend to by validating that your variables contain values/operators that you can "trust". Imagine if one of the variables contained something like `alert('gottcha!')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `eval` function:

```js
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
var p = '+';
var z = eval(x + p + y);

alert(z);
```

Comment: If you're gonna suggest using `eval` - please include appropriate warnings about the dangers of executing arbitrary code.