# Arithmetic operator sign as function name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to give an arithmetic operator sign as a function name and then call it.
I want to do something like this :

```
+(4,5) // Answer : 9
/(9,3) //Answer : 3
```

I've already seen a code sample like this but I can't remember how it assigned a name like "+" to a function in JavaScript and then called it.

Can anyone show me some tricky ways to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I really doubt you can do that.

Comment: I'm 99% certain you can't do this, and 100% certain you *shouldn't* do this.

Comment: doesnt it make more sense to just go a + b or 9/3.. Seems much easier to read then trying to dig through what you are trying to achieve. but then also no you cant assign to those operators. The closes you can go is with simple add(), sub(), mul(), div()...

Comment: I already see a tricky way and a code sample but I can't remember it. I am sure it is possible. It was something like ("+", function(){})

Comment: There is a Tricky way. I am sure. I already see a code sample.

Comment: I don't think you did, at least not in JavaScript.

Comment: You'd better go find that code sample, then, because the standard is quite clear you can't do this. You could create an object where one of the keys is `"+"`, and its value is a function, but that's not at all what your question asked. And again, why in the world do you even want this?

Comment: @AmirJalilifard you probably seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible

Comment: Do you come from a Swift background? This seems like something Swift-ian.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible

> Function names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar
>   signs (same rules as variables).

Comment: The _letters_ bit does contain **a lot** though, e.g. `function π() {return Math.PI;}`, `function ß() {return 'ss';}`, `function 漢字() {return 'Kanji';}` etc are all valid

Comment: I know after 10 years of coding with JS. But there is a tricky way! As I can remember in a code sample I saw it was written something like ("+", function(){}) . I just remember this part of code!

Comment: @PaulS.: `function 十(a, b) { return a + b; }` :)

Comment: @AmirJalilifard that looks like it is an invocation of another function which takes the string `"+"` and decides which operation to perform

Comment: @Paul. Yes. But how? I can't remember this part!

Comment: @AmirJalilifard Considering you haven't given us an accurate description of what you want, you aren't going to get an answer here unless you update your question.

Comment: I exactly want this and I am sure it is possible because I have seen a code sample. +(4,5) // Answer : 9
I think I've seen that in JavaScript Ninja book

Comment: @AmirJalilifard **That is not possible.** I don't know how to make it any more clear. You either are misremembering what you read, or you read some bad information.

Comment: @AmirJalilifard you can try amadan way like this function 十(a, b) { return a + b; } and calling will be 十(4, 5).

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: That was a joke though. (It works, to be sure, but... don't do that.)

Answer (score 2):

### You can't

> Variable / Function names can only have **Letters, Underscores, $, Numbers (if they're not the first character) along with a few other ACII, and unicode characters**

Check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names) or [**here**](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) for more information

---

## Workaround*ish*

If you are determined on having a `+` as your function name, you could use:

```
window['+'] = function (a,b) {
    return a+b;
};
```

That is bad practice and still only creates a variable *"theoretically"* named `+` and can only be invoked using:

```
window['+'](9, 10);
```

Which returns `19`

---

## What you are thinking of

The syntax you are suggesting seems like `Object.defineProperty` syntax:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, '+', {value:function () {
    alert('foo');
}});
```

---

## Try

You could create something like:

```
window.special = function(a, args) {
    var o = {
        '+': function (b,c) {
            return b+c;
        }
    };
    return o[a].apply(this, args);
};
```

Then:

```
special('+', [1, 2]);
```

Comment: You still can't invoke that as `+(4, 5)` (or even as `window.+(4, 5)`).

Comment: @Amadan I realize but it creates a function names `+`

Comment: No, it creates an anonymous function assigned to `window['+']`. See this: `a = function() {}; function b() {}; console.log(a, b)` - the first one is anonymous (despite being assigned to `a`), the second one is actually *named* `b`.

Answer (score 2):

> I know after 10 years of coding with JS. But there is a tricky way! As I can remember in a code sample I saw it was written something like `("+", function(){})`. I just remember this part of code!
>
> @Paul. Yes. But how? I can't remember this part!

Define another function that takes a parameter which tells it which method to apply, for example

```
var op = (function () {
    var fns = Object.create(null),
        slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    fns['+'] = function () { // example adder
        var i, j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
            j += arguments[i];
        return j;
    };
    // add other methods here
    return function op(operator) {
        if (operator in fns)
            return fns[operator].apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));
        throw new SyntaxError('Not a valid operator: ' + operator);
    };
}());

op('+', 1, 2, 3, 4); // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add it is possible if you really want to override the function of '+' you could essentially write

`window['+'] = function(a, b) { return a + b; }`;

But what does that do... This will add a function to the window namespace. However you still cant call it with `+(a,b)` you have to use the window namespace. Such as.

`window['+'](4,5);`

result: `9`

which really is a pain to call the window space. You are not limited to the `window` space you could use any object.