# Refactor if statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering on how I can refactor that? I'm repeating myself I feel this is not the best way to write it :

```
if (operator === "+") {
    strength += 2;
    up = 4 * strength;
    if (up > 40) up = 40;
    final.base += up;
} else if (operator === "-") {
    up = 4 * strength;
    if (up > 40) up = 40;
    final.base -= up;
    strength -= 2;
}
```

I don't really see a way to properly refactor that since position is important. Is there a way to clean this function?

Comment: The usual way to refactor out a large else-if ladder is to loop through an *associative array.*

Comment: Have a look here: https://blog.wax-o.com/2015/05/an-alternative-to-if-else-and-switch-in-javascript/

Comment: If nothing else, the `if (up > 40) up = 40;` doesn't rely on the conditional at all.

Comment: After some refactoring i think your original code is better.

Comment: I would say what you have, especially if there are only a few `operator`s is fine. It's readable, a reader of the code can easily identify what happens which each operator. That's likely more important.

Comment: @jhpratt I don't really understand your comment. up is kind of a limit. You can't add/substract more than 40 even if the result of 4*strength is over 40.

Comment: is the up variable used after this block?

Comment: I don't use it anymore after

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write it more compact, if you do not use `up` later by using `Math.min`.

```
if (operator === "+") {
    strength += 2;
    final.base += Math.min(40, 4 * strength);
} else if (operator === "-") {
    final.base -= Math.min(40, 4 * strength);
    strength -= 2;
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant idea and it respects position, thanks!

Comment: @FlickaMin if you want to update `up` and increment `base` at the same time, `final.base += up = Math.min(40, 4 * strength)`

Comment: The second approach won't work, note that `final.base` is not always incremented...

Comment: @Shidersz, that's why i added a disclaimer.

Comment: I think,you do not understand me. I believe you forgot to replace `final.base += Math.min(40, 4 * strength);` by this `final.base = final.base + (operator === "+" ?
 Math.min(40, 4 * strength) : -Math.min(40, 4 * strength));` or maybe by this: `final.base += (operator === "+" ? 1 : -1) * Math.min(40, 4 * strength);`

Comment: @Shidersz, right. i missed the different operator. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I will do something like this, for preserve `up` variable:

```
if (operator === "+")
{
    up = Math.min(4 * (strength += 2), 40);
    final.base += up;
}
else if (operator === "-")
{
    final.base -= (up = Math.min(4 * strength, 40));
    strength -= 2;
}
```

If you don't need `up` variable, can be simplified to this:

```
if (operator === "+")
{
    final.base += Math.min(4 * (strength += 2), 40);
}
else if (operator === "-")
{
    final.base -= Math.min(4 * strength, 40);
    strength -= 2;
}
```

If you don't need `up` variable and also you only have `+` and `-` operators, then you can go like this:

```
strength += (operator === "+") ? 2 : 0;
final.base += (operator === "+" ? 1 : -1) * Math.min(4 * strength, 40);
strength -= (operator === "-") ? 2 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not refactoring of `if..else` - it's about thinking ahead how Your app can grow, it's about making right choices.

In large apps with complex logic You'll have to abstract methods to make You code more flexible.

For example how about having `Operations` class that abstracts `if..else` switch, which You can extend?

```js
class Operations {
  static plus (base, strength) {
    base = parseInt(base);
    strength = parseInt(strength);
    
    strength += 2;
    base += Math.min(40, 4 * strength);
    
    return [base, strength];
  }
  
  static minus (base, strength) {
    base = parseInt(base);
    strength = parseInt(strength);
    
    base -= Math.min(40, 4 * strength);
    strength -= 2;
    
    return [base, strength];
  }

  static do (operation) {
    const operators = {
      '+' : Operations.plus,
      '-' : Operations.minus
    }

    const args = Object.values(arguments).slice(1);
    
    if (!operators[operation]) {
      return args;
    }

    return operators[operation].apply(null, args);
  }
}

   
let final = {base: 10};
let strength = 10;
let newBase, newStrength;

console.log('Before. base:', final.base, 'strength:', strength);

// NO IF ELSE ON OPERATOR (:
[newBase, newStrength] = Operations.do('+', final.base, strength);
strength = newStrength;
final.base = newBase;

console.log('After "+" operation. base:', final.base, 'strength:', strength);

[newBase, newStrength] = Operations.do('-', final.base, strength);
strength = newStrength;
final.base = newBase;

console.log('After "-" operation. base:', final.base, 'strength:', strength);
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the duplication problem, you can add a `multiplier` factor since the majority of what's changing here is just the *sign*.

```
let multiplier = 1;
if (operator === "-")
    multiplier = -1;

up = 4 * strength;
strength += multiplier * 2;
if (up > 40) up = 40;
final.base += multiplier * up;
```

## Note

This will only work if `operator` is either `-` or `+`. If it's something like `*`, this will act as if the operator is `+`

Comment: As I said just before, position is really important so I can't do something like this. If the operator is "plus" I must get the up after incrementing, if the operator is "minus" it's after.

Comment: yeah you're right @num8er. This will only work if the operator is either `+` or `-`. Good catch, I'm adding an edit

Answer (score 1):

you could put the operations in an object :

```
const obj = {
    "+" : {
        strength : prevStrength => prevStrength + 2,
        finalBase: (prevFinalBase , up) =>  prevFinalBase + Math.min(40, 4 * strength)
    },  
    "-" : {
        strength : prevStrength => prevStrength - 2,
        finalBase: (prevFinalBase , up) => prevFinalBase - Math.min(40, 4 * strength)
    }
}

strength = obj[operator].strength(strength);
finalBase = obj[operator].finalBase(finalBase);
```

```js
var operator = "+";
var strength = 3;
var finalBase = 5;

const obj = {
  "+": {
    strength: prevStrength => prevStrength + 2,
    finalBase: (prevFinalBase, up) => prevFinalBase + Math.min(40, 4 * strength)
  },
  "-": {
    strength: prevStrength => prevStrength - 2,
    finalBase: (prevFinalBase, up) => prevFinalBase - Math.min(40, 4 * strength)
  }
}

strength = obj[operator].strength(strength);
finalBase = obj[operator].finalBase(finalBase);

console.log({
  strength,
  finalBase
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing the logic as a series of conditional ternary operator statements:

```
let isAdd = operator === '+'
strength += isAdd ? 2 : 0;
up = 4 * strength;
if(up > 40) up = 40;
final.base += isAdd ? up : (-1 * up)
strength -= isAdd ? 0 : 2;
```

Comment: True! I think there are much better answers above!

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
 /*ASCII Code For "-" = 45, "+" = 43*/
 operator = (44-operator.charCodeAt(0));
 if(operator > 0) strength += 2;
 up = 4*strength;
 if(up > 40) up = 40;
 final.base = final.base + (operator*up);
 if(operator < 0) strength -= 2;
```