# Javascript JSON file filter with object as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, destructuring

I'm a newbie in Javascript and I'm trying to understand the **destructuring** approach also with object literals. So what I'm trying to do is to create a function which has two types of *arguments*: 1. It's a JSON data file which I want to iterate. 2. An object literal with a random value assigned. So I'm trying to iterate with this object value passed as a parameter and filter with the data from the JSON file with an **if statement** inside the array of objects iterator. And add to **arr** all the object which match.
Thanks everyone in advance.

Array of objects:

```
[
  { "id": 44, "hours": 100,"finished": false },
  { "id": 22, "hours": 80,"finished": false },
  { "id": 65, "hours": 34,"finished": false },
  { "id": 1098, "hours": 21,"finished": true  },
  { "id": 2, "hours": 67,"finished": false },
  { "id": 765, "hours": 32,"finished": false },
  { "id": 223, "hours": 555,"finished": false },
  { "id": 986, "hours": 2,"finished": false }
]
```

main.js

```
const data = require('./example.json')

function dataFilter (items, {id: _id, hours: _hours, finished: _finished}) {

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let arr = [];
    if (items[i].id === _id) {
        arr.push(items[i])
    }
    else if (items[i].hours >= _hours){
        arr.push(items[i])
    }
    else if (items[i].finished === finished){
        arr.push(items[i])
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(dataFilter(data,{ id: 65 }));
console.log(dataFilter(data,{ hours: 30 }));
```

Comment: Where you have auto, shouldn't be finished?? In the else if statement

Comment: @MiguelCruz yes sorry , edited already

Comment: But i didn't understand yet what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: "JSON data file": although your read data from a JSON file, the function parameter is not expecting JSON at all: it expects a JavaScript array.

Comment: I miss a question here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: @trincot you mean that this is not the way to iterate through an array of objects?

Comment: @PUPU, no I mean your question is stating something that is not true. It says that the first argument is a JSON file, but that is not what you are doing. It is a comment about how you name things. JSON file is not the same thing as a JavaScript object.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha trying to add to **arr** all the objects which match with the function calling parameters

Comment: @trincot you are right dude , my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need destructuring, what you need is array filter.

You also forgot to set a default `{}` so you can access `undefined` keys:

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

```js
const data = [
  { "id": 44, "hours": 100,"finished": false },
  { "id": 22, "hours": 80,"finished": false },
  { "id": 65, "hours": 34,"finished": false },
  { "id": 1098, "hours": 21,"finished": true  },
  { "id": 2, "hours": 67,"finished": false },
  { "id": 765, "hours": 32,"finished": false },
  { "id": 223, "hours": 555,"finished": false },
  { "id": 986, "hours": 2,"finished": false },
  { "id": 1986, "hours": 30,"finished": false },
];

function dataFilter (items, {id: _id, hours: _hours, finished: _finished} = {}) {
  return items.filter((item) => item.id === _id || item.hours >= _hours || item.finished === _finished);
}

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
<pre>
ID: 65
${JSON.stringify(dataFilter(data,{ id: 65 }), null, 2)}
  
HOURS: 30
${JSON.stringify(dataFilter(data,{ hours: 30 }), null, 2)}
</pre>
`
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

### Approach with multiple filters

It is also possible to use more than one filter at once:

```js
const data = [
  { "id": 44, "hours": 100,"finished": false },
  { "id": 22, "hours": 80,"finished": false },
  { "id": 65, "hours": 34,"finished": false },
  { "id": 1098, "hours": 21,"finished": true  },
  { "id": 2, "hours": 67,"finished": false },
  { "id": 765, "hours": 32,"finished": false },
  { "id": 223, "hours": 555,"finished": false },
  { "id": 986, "hours": 2,"finished": false },
  { "id": 1986, "hours": 30,"finished": false },
];

function dataFilter (items, filters = {}) {
  // this will create a list of function on the fly for every `filters` you pass.
  const fnList = Object.keys(filters)
    .map((key) => (list) => list.filter((item) => item[key] === filters[key]));
    
  let res = [...items];
  while (cursor = fnList.shift()) {
    res = cursor(res);
  }
  return res;
}

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
<pre>
ID: 44, HOURS: 100
${JSON.stringify(dataFilter(data,{ id: 44, hours: 100 }), null, 2)}
  
ID: 2, HOURS: 67
${JSON.stringify(dataFilter(data,{ id: 2 }), null, 2)}
</pre>
`
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

If you want to specify the operators used for the comparaison, use a fonction as explained here: [Are Variable Operators Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thx, this approach looks cool, but I was trying to pass e.g 3 values as a parameter    _{id: 45, hours: 10, finished: true}_  so the result will be just the objects which match with those parameters.

Comment: I have added an approach with multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to be able to filter the data by any combination of the three items in that object.

```
function filterFactory({id, hours, finished}) {
  return function filter(item) {
    let isGoodValue = false;
    if (id !== undefined && item.id === id) isGoodValue = true;

    // for the second and third checks we'll short-circuit if it already
    // passed an earlier check
    if (!isGoodValue && hours !== undefined && item.hours >= hours) isGoodValue = true;
    if (!isGoodValue && finished !== undefined && item.finished === finished) isGoodValue = true;
    return isGoodValue;
  };
}

data.filter(filterFactory({id: 2}));
```

Note that we're using the native [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on arrays. `filterFactory` is a factory that makes callbacks to pass to filter based on one or more of the three factors you're filtering on.