# Is there a simple way to add some javascript to Excel and VBA Basic?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I am trying to write some macro code for excel. VBA basic is similar to power shell script which I am familiar with. However, some of what I need to do cannot be accomplished in VBA basic and according to microsoft documentation it must be done in javascript or C#. I am not proficient in javascript, but it is easy enough to piece together the basic code from the microsoft documentation.

I cannot figure out how to write addins using visual studio. It seems very complex and involves a large file structure. Is there a way to write small snippets of javascript and call it in a vba module? Or another way to accomplish what I need?

I know python, but I don't think I can use it for this.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: You can run Jscript see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037655)